# Most efficient method to expire records after 10 minutes from creation in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I want to implement a system in sql server that will automatically delete each record after 10 minutes. 
Since this expiry time will be different for every row,
it means that using a job would be incredibly ineffective in performing this task.

What is the most efficient way to achieve this?

Of course, there are other problems,job such as every 10 runs, and if row insert at 9: 1 ,
Because jobs will be created once every ten minutes and this row must be removed at 9:11, at 9:20 deleted

Comment: Why removing? you can use a `WHERE` statement to check if the record is already expired and use a job to remove the rows occasionally?

Comment: I totally agree with Willem. You can use a column to keep create date and run a delete job every night to delete all recrod that are expired at that point if you really want to delete them.